# Applying filter to an Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

How can we apply filter to an **Observable** so that we could get data based on some condition? My requirement is I want to filter out the users from **userObservable** whose status is "**Approved**".

Below is my http service method.

```
getUserList(){
    return this.httpClient.get<UserModel[]>(environment.userListUrl);
}
```

Below is the UserModel

```
export class UserModel{
   userName: string;
   userStatus: string;
}
```

And this what I am trying to do but not sure how I can apply filter so that I can get the Users whose **userStatus** is "**Approved**"

```
const userObservable$: Observable<UserModel[]>=this.userService.getUserList(this.cmpnyId);
observable$.pipe(filter(....<Need help here>));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check RxJS's documentation on the [map](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/map) operator:

```
filteredObservable$ = userObservable$.pipe(
  map(users => users.filter(user => user.userStatus == "Approved"))
)
```

You should map the value of the Observable to a new filtered array. The `filter` operator that you are using can only be used to allow or discard values emitted by the Observable, it is unrelated to the `.filter` array function, which filters certain elements out of an array.

Answer (score 6):

You can use it in the service in order to keep business logic into the services.

Code sample:

```
enum Status{
    approved = 'Approved'
}

getUserList(){
    return this.httpClient.get<UserModel[]>(environment.userListUrl)
   .pipe(
    map(users => 
    users.filter(user => 
    user.userStatus == Status.approved))
}
```

Note, please use Enum for something like this in order u want to make it easier for future status changes.